# How to interpret scoped variables next to each other within Lambda Terms and CL-terms?

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

In both the lambda calculus ($\lambda$-calculus) and Combinatory Logic (CL), we have the notion of function application. For example:

\begin{array}
& \left( \lambda x . x \right) y = y & \text{(function application) } \\
([ x ] . x)  y = y & \text{(function application) } \\
\end{array}

Fair enough. But, in each of these respective systems, how to interpret the following?

\begin{array}
\left( \lambda x . \underbrace{xy}_{\text{?}}) \\
([ x ] . \underbrace{xy}_{\text{?}})\\
\end{array}

Is $xy$ inside these scopes *also* just function application?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I know $xy$ doesn't further reduce to anything within these expressions, but I am still curious as to how this term should be interpreted by a human.